# MySQL: Comparing ID with negative (-) sign, is it slowing the performance

Tags: mysql, join

I have two main tables, **Person_A** and **Person_B**. Every time Person_A join as a member, I move it to table Person_B. Both A & B have properties, supposedly: house, work, etc. So, I also have table House, and Work.

But then, I want to make it easier by having one reference tables of **House** and **Work** for both Person_A & Person_B, so I put the reference information into ref tables, which are: **ref_person_work**, **ref_person_house**, both is used for joining the tables later on.

But, to differentiate between Person_A & Person_B on the ref tables, I use a negative (-) sign in the ref table for Person_A, and unsigned for Person_B.

Now, I just uploaded about 150k++ data of Person_A, while Person_B tables is still in small number as only few Person_A have joined. So,, the query for Person_B is always fast. No issue.

But the problem occurs now on Person_A query. I'm getting like about 3 to 5 seconds just to get 100 rows.

The example query may be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person_A A
LEFt JOIN ref_person_house refH ON refH.person_id = A.id * -1
LEFT JOIN House H ON H.id = refH.house_id
LEFt JOIN ref_person_work refW ON refW.person_id = A.id * -1
LEFT JOIN Work W ON W.id = refW.work_id
```

*** notice how I have to multiply by -1 to get a negative number for Person_A*

Also, I already index all the necessary columns.

Does this sign affecting the query?

Comment: With 150K rows in the `Person_A` table combined with 4 `JOIN` operations, it doesn't sound too unreasonable to me for the query to be taking 3-5 seconds.  Just because your result set only contains 100 rows does not change the scale of the query you are performing.

Comment: thank you. it really changes my perspective now. I'll try first, and we'll see what I'll get.